# ScrollView does not work

Tags: android

I have added ScrollView but it does not display in app and especially Spinner does not  displayed when screen size is smaller. How can I add a ScrollView?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/timeclock_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <AnalogClock
            android:id="@+id/AnalogClock1"
            android:hand_hour="@drawable/customhour"
            android:hand_minute="@drawable/customminute" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtcompanyidentifier"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtuserdisplay"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLastpounch"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnchkin"
                android:background="@drawable/new_chkin" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnchkout"
                android:background="@drawable/new_checkout" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <DigitalClock
            android:id="@+id/digitalClock2"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            d:paddingBottom="2dp" />

        <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner2" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/notes"
                android:hint="Notes:"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </Spinner>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Spinner>
    </Spinner>

    <RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I noticed a few things right off the top. You have android:orientation set for RelativeLayouts, which are not needed. You only use android:orientation for LinearLayouts. Also, you did not define layout_height and layout_width for all the widgets you are using in there. You need them for each and every widget. Is this code even compiling? It shouldn't!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't display anything because a scrollview only supports one ViewGroup as a child and you have 2 RelativeLayout and 1 spinner. You have to put all you view into one RelativeLayout for example.

In your case If you delete these:

```
<Spinner>
</Spinner>

<RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

On the end it has to work.

Hope to help :)

Comment: EditTextView always focus and keyboard is always appeared.how can i avaoid

Comment: InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(EditTextVariableName.getWindowToken(), 0);

Comment: Thanks for your Help.  notes=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.notes);
   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
     imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(notes.getWindowToken(),0);

Comment: i have added above code..as you given  but still it shows me keyboard.it does not disappear Keyboard

Comment: You should have some code wrong or something, cause this code hide the keyboar 100% sure. you can show more code of your programm